# Efficient Multiple TastyPie Resource Updates Across Multiple Tables

Tags: python, django, django-models, tastypie

What is the most efficient way to insert (or update) multiple records in a TastyPie resource, where multiple tables are being updated?

I have the following entry being sent via AngularJS:

```
var visitEntry = 
{
    visitor: {
        name: "Test Name",
        organization: $scope.org + ", of Testington"
    },
    date: null,
    group: {
        organization: $scope.org,
        purpose: $scope.purpose,
        date: $scope.date + " " + $scope.time,
        host: $scope.host
    }
};
```

This is a visitor log entry.  In it, only the "visitor" entry will change when recording a new group visiting our lab - the `group` entry will be the same across any number of people being logged.

Say 40 people are coming in a group.  How can I best update the above entry to be most efficient?

Can I do something like:

```
var visitorArray = [ { ... }, { ... }, { ... } ];

var visitEntry =
{
    visitor: visitorArray,
    date: null,
    group: {
        ...
    }
};
```

Or will I need to loop each of visitors recorded in our web form and apply them with a unique `visitorEntry` object via a bulk PATCH to TastyPie?  This is what we do now, but it seems wasteful with the `group` always being the same.